# Problem with loading data in List View from SQlite

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was making an app and ran into this problem. When I add this function, arguments.putStringArray ("main", mdb.get School Lessons ("monday")), I have a crash, but without this function, the program interface opens without passing data to the ListView.

[Mistakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg1Ng.png)

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"MN", "TU", "WED", "THU", "FR", "SAT"};


    public int getBtn_pos() {
        return btn_pos;
    }

    int btn_pos;
    Context context;


    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        DataBase myDB = new DataBase(context);
        if (position == 1) {
            btn_pos = position;
            if (myDB.getSchoolLessons("monday").length != 0) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putStringArray("main", myDB.getSchoolLessons("monday"));
                Fragment_school fragment = new Fragment_school();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                return fragment;
            }
            return new Fragment_school();
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace, of the error

Comment: I added bugs,sorry forgot about that.

Comment: `myDB.getSchoolLessons("monday")` is returning null, or the problem exists inside of the List's Adapter and not the Fragment's Adapter.